# Extract section from Premiere without re-compression

Tags: premiere

Is there a way to use premiere like the hundreds of other "cheap" video cutters out there?

I need a quick way to select a portion of video, for example our source footage is often 1h long, and we need to cut out many 30s clips.

However, this needs to be a fast process, and we cant re-compress those clips on the export.

We have premiere pro, can this do the job? Every time I try, it wants to compress the footage.

Comment: What's the source container and AV codec? Is the OS Windows?

Comment: We need to know what @Mulvya asked, however also compression is how you export in any editor - you HAVE to "rewrite" the data into a new file (otherwise there is no new file).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question abandoned by the asker, but I use `ffmpeg` to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux) sections.

## Example 1: Single output

Skip first 14 minutes and make a 30 second output:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:14:00 -i input -t 30 -c copy -map 0 output
```

- This will not re-encode, so the process is quick and preserves the quality.
- Depending on your input format the output may not be exactly from the desired time, but usually it's close enough. See the `-ss` option in the [FFmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) for more info.

## Example 2: One segment of every *n* seconds

Use the segment muxer:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 30 -f segment output%03d.foo
```

- This will not re-encode, so the process is quick and preserves the quality.
- Note that splitting may not be accurate, unless you force the reference stream key-frames at the given time. See the [segment muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) for more info.

Comment: Cool, but the poster asks specifically for Premiere.

Comment: @kazanaki More than 3 years ago... This answer is really targeted to others.

Answer (score 1):

You can export your clips using one of the lossless options (e.g. Quicktime/PNG or Quicktime/Animation).

Notice that this will result in very large files so make sure that you have enough space.